# sql server freetexttable in unrelated multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to use freetexttable in unrelated multiple tables? Below is the query I have constructed for a single table.

```
 SELECT XXXX,XXXX,XXXX,XXXX 
 FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
 FREETEXTTABLE(table1, (XXXX, XXXX, XXXX),'Search Keyword') AS f 
 ON table1.ID= f.[key] 
 WHERE f.rank > 0 
 ORDER BY table1.Date desc  ;
```

I want to search multiple unrelated tables and return the best match as result set based on ranking, latest date. How do I achieve this?

Comment: when you say unrelated, do you mean there's no way at all to tie the results together?  table1 has no relation to table 2?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if you're looking for a stacked set (UNION) or just full text searching across a number of lookup tables

Comment: yes table 1 has no relation with table 2. For example, I am searching for 'Health care', the most relevant match should be displayed at the top after searching in different tables(at least 5 tables)

Comment: It is a full text searching across a number of unrelated tables

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
 SELECT [Date]
      , [Rank]
      , XXXX
      , XXXX
 FROM   table1
        INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(table1, ( XXXX, XXXX, XXXX ), 'Search Keyword')
        AS f ON table1.ID = f.[key]
 WHERE  f.rank > 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [Date]
      , [Rank]
      , XXXX
      , XXXX
 FROM   table2
        INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(table2, ( XXXX, XXXX, XXXX ), 'Search Keyword')
        AS f ON table1.ID = f.[key]
 WHERE  f.rank > 0
 ORDER BY [RANK]
      , [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Above query returns records with latest date. I would like the search to be more relevant. Consider this scenario - I have heading and description in the SELECT in addition to date and rank. If the search keyword is present in the heading, it should be given more weightage than in the description. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Full text search has some quirks.  If you're building an index that spans multiple columns, each of those columns is examined together, and rank is combined across them.  To do what you're asking, you'd need to search each column separately, and weight one column more than another.

Comment: How do I accomplish that? Can you quote an example please?